# jmonkeyengine platform does not start/launch

Tags: java-me, jmonkeyengine

I need help on this please..
I have installed JME sdk 3 in windows 7 professional 32 bit system
I have jdk also already installed.

When i try to start JME platform using the icon in start menu or the the jmonkeyplatform.exe file in program files/jmonkeyplatform/bin , it lauches the startup logo. It says reading,loading modules, turning on modules and then starting modules. But after that it suddenly disaperars. Nothing happens , no error msg.

I have nvidia graphics card in my system

What do I have to do? Please help. I also uninstalled and re-installed. Is it the problem with version of jme? Or some problem with with my graphics card setting?

Please guide..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally its working now.
I uninstalled the jmonkey platform and downloaded another version from here
http://jmonkeyengine.org/downloads/ --->jMonkeyEngine 3 SDK – Windows (32-bit)

I installed it and it worked.

May be the earlier JME 3 was not suitable for my system.

Thanks anyway..
www.shankysportal.com